# How to save an image to Camera folder in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save a photo to Camera folder which my app takes. This is what I am trying

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "PlumFastJob" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Camera");

    if(!storageDir.exists()){

        boolean s = new File(storageDir.getPath()).mkdirs();

        if(!s){
            Log.v("not", "not created");
        }
        else{
            Log.v("cr","directory created");
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.v("directory", "directory exists");
    }

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".png",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    uriOfImage = Uri.parse(image.getPath());
    return image;
}
```

I have also tried Enviornment.Directory_DCIM and Environment.Directory_Pictures. But both of them creates a folder called DCIM and Pictures.

This just creates another folder called Camera and saves it.

Here is my file provider.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="." />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All camera apps nowadays save to a `Camera` directory inside the `DCIM` directory.

So you have to use

```
File dir = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
      Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
```

Comment: This just throws an exception: Permission denied. WRITE_STORAGE permission is active.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting path  `File storageDir Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Camera");`
this will create the folder with name of "Camera"

> DIRECTORY_DCIM The traditional location for pictures and videos when
>   mounting the device as a camera.

```
File musicDirectory = new File( getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM));
```

> DIRECTORY_PICTURES Standard directory in which to place pictures that
>   are available to the user.

```
File musicDirectory = new File( getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: I tried both these on the emulator but both of them creates a Folder called DCIM and Pictures. I want to save it to the Camera Folder which already exists.